# "libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, libreoffice

I installed LibreOffice on my AWS EC2 instance following [this script](https://gist.github.com/nl5887/ec5462b1671451163b29). The installation happened successfully but when I try to convert a file:

```
/opt/libreoffice5.3/program/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.docx
```

I get the following error message:

```
/opt/libreoffice5.3/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I installed the missing library with yum: `sudo yum install libdbus-glib-1.so.2`. The installation happened successfully but it still doesn't work properly giving me the same error as before.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try `yum install Xvfb` and then `Xvfb :99 & export DISPLAY=:99`, run the program again.

Comment: @mootmoot thanks for your comment. When running Xvfb :99 & export DISPLAY=:99 I get this error: _XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.

Comment: Nevertheless, try this first,  you might not required the Xvfb.  Here say you need to spcecify an explicit i386 :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/656844/libreoffice-5-does-not-starts-error-while-loading-shared-libraries

Comment: @mootmoot Thanks for you comment. Would you know how can I install using yum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution outlined [here](https://www.docmosis.com/node/114) worked for me:

```
sudo yum install libXinerama.x86_64 cups-libs dbus-glib
```

Or if you are using Elastic Beanstalk:

```
packages:
    yum:
        libXinerama.x86_64: []
        cups-libs: []
        dbus-glib: []
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To deliver the project I had to se another tool but I will test your answer and give you the feedback

Comment: I know it's a bit of a late answer, but hopefully it will work for you too and it could make a good reference for someone in the future. :)